# Properly Displaying XML in a Web Browser

Tags: xml

I am an extreme XML n00b and just started my first project. But when I open the .xml file, It displays the elements as well as the text. How do I get it to just display the text?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE dhml [ 
    <!ELEMENT dhml (header, body, footer)>
    <!ELEMENT header (#PCDATA)*>
    <!ELEMENT body (p+)>
    <!ELEMENT footer (#PCDATA)*>
    <!ELEMENT p (#PCDATA)*>
    ]>
    <dhml>
    <header>Hello</header>
    <body>
        <p>Greetings</p>
        <p>YOLO</p>
    </body>
    <footer>Goodbye</footer>
    </dhml>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Serve it with a suitable Content-Type (`application/xml` for example)
2. [Associate a stylesheet](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-stylesheet/) with it.

Generally speaking though, if you want to write markup for rendering as a document in a web browser, write HTML instead of inventing your own language (or, at least, transform it to HTML before serving to the client).